# C#/C++: Launch an application and handle its I/O calls to the system

Tags: c#, c++, io, filesystems

I need to launch other application and handle it's I/O operations. So when it tries to read/write a file, I need to catch this and change the path.

It should be possible, because there is programs that do something like this (like ModOrganizer).

The thing is I don't want to use File System Filter Drivers. I don't want to make users of my application to install such thing.

As I see, ModOrganizer does the trick with several ways including `proxy.dll`, `hooks` e.t.c. Somehow, it achieves the goal that almost any program can be launched from it and ModOrganizer will handle requests to the certain directory.

There is source code on [github](https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer/), but I don't really get it. That is why I'm asking this here.

Again, ModOrganizer achieves this **without** decompiling every possible program to know, where to inject. And it doesn't use System Filters.

(Please explain your minuses. Otherwise how am I going to improve my questions in the future?)

Comment: Look into [FilterDrivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/what-is-a-file-system-filter-driver-)

Comment: No exactly what I meant. Programs like ModOrganizer don't install any drivers. They just.. launch another application from itself and somehow the magic works.

Comment: There's no magic. It replaces filesystem functions with custom functions. You must run with admin rights. Good chances you may be seen as a virus too. This is totally unsupported and can lead to serious crashes, highly dependent on Windows version, updates, etc. also dependent on how the target program uses file system, etc (it was originally developped for a few games, not for any app). Relevant code seems to be here: https://github.com/TanninOne/usvfs/blob/master/usvfs/hookmanager.cpp

Comment: @user64675 About this other application.. _"When it tries to read/write a file, I need to catch this and change the path"_ is it doing this automatically (hidden)? or is there dialog box involved (for user to set Filename, button OK, button Cancel, etc)?...

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to modify import table of every module in a process.

It looks like the program you mentioned uses technique similar to what is described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed under section "*Injecting DLL by using CreateRemoteThread() API function*". But instead of using remote thread it forces main program thread to do its job (see function injectDLL):

https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer/blob/4a582e524dd012ed9d5fdb4f9c97aab22c8dac85/src/spawn.cpp

Notice there is a flag `CREATE_SUSPENDED` passed to `CreateProcess` function - this helps it to stub all functions before main thread is able to execute anything.

Instead of patching import table it inserts stub written in assembly (see function injectDLL):

https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer/blob/4a582e524dd012ed9d5fdb4f9c97aab22c8dac85/src/shared/inject.cpp

Jeffrey Richter had a good example on how to patch import table in his book "Windows via C/C++". You can try to find and read a complete book or you can just check code here: https://github.com/lattesir/WindowsViaCPP/blob/master/22-LastMsgBoxInfoLib/APIHook.cpp

But your program will probably look like a virus for any anti-virus software.

Comment: +1 For the very important note that Windows API hooks are quite commonly used by malicious software.  You are effectively trying to hijack another `Process` and this _will_ get picked up by anti-virus software and related.  There's a real possibility other software will successfully stop your hook attempt.

Answer (score 4):

ModOrganizer uses remote thread injection to run a custom library (dll) in the context of the target process. The library then goes on to manipulate the process from within and gain control over it.

This is one of the most-known techniques user-space code injection and work *pretty well* with most processes.

**Note:** ModOrganizer doesn't support 64bit binaries, see the following exception in their code:

> throw windows_error("failed to access thread context. Please note that Mod Organizer does not support 64bit binaries!");

**Step 1: Obtaining a `HANDLE` to target thread & process**

To interact with different threads & processes on the machine, you first have to obtain `HANDLE`s to them.

The method in ModOrganizer that obtains that handle is `bool spawn(..)`, and more specifically the following line:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
BOOL success =
     ::CreateProcess(nullptr,
                     commandLine,
                     nullptr, nullptr, // no special process or thread attributes
                     inheritHandles,   // inherit handles if we plan to use stdout or stderr reroute
                     CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB | (suspended ? CREATE_SUSPENDED : 0), // create suspended so I have time to inject the DLL
                     nullptr,          // same environment as parent
                     currentDirectory, // current directory
                     &si, &pi          // startup and process information
                     );
```

As you can see, this line obtains a PROCESS_INFORMATION object using `CreateProcess`. We now can extract the process `HANDLE` from `pi.hProcess` and the thread `HANDLE` from `pi.hThread`.

Moreover, this command not only obtains `HANDLE`s to the target process, but also puts it into **suspended** mode (`CREATE_SUSPENDED`). This allows us to manipulate it as we wish, and then resume its execution.

**Step 2: Injecting your own dll to a target process**

The injector method is the `void injectDLL(..)` method defined inside `src/shared/inject.cpp`.

The goal of this method is to load the dll specified by `dllname` into the target thread `threadHandle` inside the target process `processHandle`.

Let's go over the important stuff:

- `TParameters parameters;` - This line and the 4 following ones allocate and set the values of a `TParameters` struct to include the path of the dll file we want to load into the target process and the parameters we will pass to the init function inside that dll file
- `::LoadLibrary(__TEXT("kernel32.dll"))` - Load `kernel32.dll` into our process space
- `::GetProcAddress(k32mod, "LoadLibraryA")` - Get the address of `LoadLibraryA` method inside the `kernel32.dll`
- `::GetProcAddress(k32mod, "GetProcAddress")` - Get the address of `GetProcAddress` method inside the `kernel32.dll`
- `::VirtualAllocEx(..)` - Allocate virtual memory inside the target process
- `::WriteProcessMemory(.., &parameters, ..)` - Write the `parameters` struct we created earlier into the virtual memory we allocated inside the target process
- `BYTE stubLocal[] = { .. }` - Generate shell code that loads the dll inside the target process, and then call the `Init` function inside the dll with the values from the `parameters` struct
- `PBYTE stubRemote = reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(::VirtualAllocEx(.., sizeof(stubLocal), ..))` - Allocate virtual memory inside our target process to accommodate our shell code. Save the address of the memory segment we allocated inside `stubRemote`
- `::GetThreadContext(threadHandle, &threadContext)` - Get the context of the target process, including the `IP` (Instruction Pointer) which points to the next instruction to execute
- `::WriteProcessMemory(.., reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(stubLocal), ..)` - Write the shell code to the virtual memory we allocated in the target process
- `threadContext.Eip = (ULONG)stubRemote;` - Set the `IP` of the target process to the location of our shell code
- `::SetThreadContext(...)` - Resume the execution of the target process. The execution resumes at the address we set for `IP`, thus executing our injected shell code that loads the desired dll file and calling the `Init` function inside it, and once our method is finished, it returns execution to the original address inside the target process as if nothing has happened.

At this point, our library is fully loaded inside the target process, and has had its chance to do all kinds of nasty hooks. But what exactly do the dlls we load do inside the target process?

**Step 3: Understand the loaded dll**

ModOrganizer actually has separate repositories for the injected dll: **[modorganizer-hookdll](https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer-hookdll)**

The main module of the dll is defined in `dllmain.cpp\h`. This module:

- Defines all the hooked method:

  ```
  // hook declarations
  CreateProcessA_type CreateProcessA_reroute = CreateProcessA;
  CreateProcessW_type CreateProcessW_reroute = CreateProcessW;
  [..]
  GetModuleFileNameA_type GetModuleFileNameA_reroute = GetModuleFileNameA;
  GetModuleFileNameW_type GetModuleFileNameW_reroute = GetModuleFileNameW;
  ```
- Defines the `Init` function which is the method our shell code executes after loading the dll
- Calls the `InitHooks()` method that is responsible for initializing all the hooks used by the application

---

At this point, I hope you have a clear picture of the steps and the APIs you have to use to achieve your goal, and understand which functions from ModOrganizer's code you should reuse.

**Development Tip:** I would recommend compiling your own dummy executable that prints `Hello world!` to the console every second, and testing your injector on it. From my own experience, developing such tools takes time and surgical precision. Don't scare off easily when your target crashes and make sure to add debug prints (If you print from your injected dll, you should see it print to the same console as the `Hello world!`s).

---

**64bit systems**

I saw some links that stating that ModOrganizer development is stopping and there's going to be a new mod manager that will be way more customizable, made by the same development team, so maybe they decided to skip 64bit support for it.

It is entirely possible to implement this for 64bit applications, **but**, it is harder to inject into a 32bit application running inside a 64bit system (Using the [WOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows) infrastructure).

To change the existing code to support 64bit, I presume that step 1 might not require any changes, step 2 requires **at least** some adjustments to the shell code (the assembly instructions differ) and step 3 (the injected dlls) should be **at least** recompiled, and some of the hooked APIs might change.

---

**More techniques and guides**

Apart from the technique ModOrganizer uses, here are some tutorials and references:

- Dll injection using CreateRemoteThread: Very similar, but it creates a thread in the remote process that loads the dll. A detailed tutorial can be found [here](http://www.coderbag.com/Threading/DLL-Injection-Using-Remote-Thread).
- [InjectProc](https://github.com/secrary/InjectProc) project (Github) that supports multiple injection implementations as a reference.
- [EasyHook](https://github.com/EasyHook/EasyHook) project (Github) that support 32-bit and 64-bit DLL injections.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. I have a question: why do you think ModOrganizer doesn't support x64 binaries? API injection just doesn't work for x64 or there is a way but MO developer just didn't implement it?

Comment: @user64675, I added some comments about 64bit injections

Answer (score 3):

This is typically achieved by dynamically patching up the remote process in memory to do the following:

1. The first few instructions (typically 5 bytes) of the target function are replaced with an unconditional jump to a detour function.
2. Instructions from the target function are preserved in a trampoline function.
3. The detour function invokes the target function after examining and / or modifying its parameters.

This effectively intercepts an arbitrary binary function; in your case it's going to be a Win32 API call. This process is described in great detail in the following white paper:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/huntusenixnt99.pdf

The greatest challenge is figuring out instruction boundaries and copying them to the trampoline function. Because this process is finicky and tedious, and it differs between different versions of the OS, and between 32-bit and 64-bit binaries, you probably don't want to do it yourself. It so happens that Microsoft created (by the author of the white paper above) and has maintained a library to do just this kind of work, called detours:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/

The 32-bit version of the detours library is available for free, but the problem is that in order to support 64-bit binaries, you would have to purchase a commercial license which last I checked cost in the thousands of dollars. There are open source alternatives, however. You came across one yourself, InjectProc and MinHook are among others.

For demonstration purposes, let's use MinHook, as it's still actively maintained and has been shown to work across multiple iterations of Windows for both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.

https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook

Now that we have our hooking library the question if how do we get it into the target process so it can do its patching work to begin with? This is typically achieved through a technique called dll injection. This involves writing to target process memory, which is OK because it will be a child process of your process (the actual target function patching is done within the context of the target process), but your application might end up being flagged by anti-virus software because of it. The patching / hooking of a function in a remote process involves several steps:

1. Your injector application launches the remote process.
2. Your hook dll is loaded into the remote process via CreateRemoteThread.
3. Your hook dll, upon initialization, patches up the target function by redirecting calls to it to your detour function.
4. The detour function invokes the target function through the trampoline.

Let's demonstrate by trying to hook the ReadFile function in Notepad.exe, which we will launch as a child process of our process.

This is our hook dll:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MinHook.h"

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *READFILE)(HANDLE, LPVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
READFILE fpReadFile = NULL;
BOOL WINAPI DetourReadFile(HANDLE hFile, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(FILE_NAME_INFO)+sizeof(WCHAR) * MAX_PATH;
    FILE_NAME_INFO *info = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NAME_INFO *>(malloc(size));
    memset(info, 0, size);
    info->FileNameLength = MAX_PATH;
    GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileNameInfo, info, (DWORD)size);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, info->FileName, L"HOOK ReadFile", NULL);
    free(info);
    return fpReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, lpOverlapped);
}

extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        MH_Initialize();
        MH_CreateHook(&ReadFile, &DetourReadFile, reinterpret_cast<void**>((LPVOID)&fpReadFile));

        MH_EnableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
    }
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        MH_DisableHook(MH_ALL_HOOKS);
        MH_Uninitialize();
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

The ReadFile target function is patched with MiniHook by invoking MH_Initialize, MH_CreateHook and MH_EnableHook. And all our detoured ReadFile does is show a message box with the file name and invoke the original ReadFile.

This is our main injector application:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef DWORD(WINAPI *fp_NtCreateThreadEx_t)(
    PHANDLE ThreadHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
    LPVOID lpParameter,
    BOOL CreateSuspended,
    DWORD dwStackSize,
    LPVOID Unknown1,
    LPVOID Unknown2,
    LPVOID Unknown3);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* dllPath = ".\\HookDll.dll";

    void* pLoadLibrary = (void*)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA");

    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));

    CreateProcessA(0, "notepad.exe", 0, 0, 1, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 0, 0, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    void* pReservedSpace = VirtualAllocEx(processInformation.hProcess, NULL, strlen(dllPath), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(processInformation.hProcess, pReservedSpace, dllPath, strlen(dllPath), NULL);

    HANDLE hThread = NULL;
    fp_NtCreateThreadEx_t fp_NtCreateThreadEx = NULL;
    fp_NtCreateThreadEx = (fp_NtCreateThreadEx_t)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtCreateThreadEx");
    fp_NtCreateThreadEx(
        &hThread, 
        0x2000000, 
        NULL, 
        processInformation.hProcess, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)pLoadLibrary,
        pReservedSpace, 
        FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    VirtualFreeEx(processInformation.hProcess, pReservedSpace, strlen(dllPath), MEM_COMMIT);

    return 0;
}
```

It launches notepad.exe, loads our hook dll into it via NtCreateThreadEx (this works on Windows 7 and up, not sure about previous versions of Windows) and lets the dll handle the rest of the work. If you need the dll to communicate information back to the launcher process, that's a different question.